# C# Marshal typedef char T_STRING[MAX_STRING_SIZE]

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

How to Marshal a:

```
[C++]
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 255
typedef char T_STRING[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
typedef struct
{
    unsigned long m_ID;
    T_STRING m_name;
} Result;
```

In C#?

Currently I am doing this (but it does not work):

```
[C#]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Result
{
    public uint m_ID;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 255)]
    public char[] m_name;
}
```

I have tried to use a IntPtr instead of char[] with equal non-working result. Both with and without [MarshalAs(...)].

Comment: Without having a C# compiler at hand, what is happening? Compilation errors? Runtime errors?

Comment: "It does not work" are words that should be avoided in a question. You really should include error messages.

Comment: Sorry, the error it gives is a "System.TypeLoadException".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marshal it like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Result
{
    public uint m_ID;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 255)]
    public string m_name;
}
```

Comment: This works. I will set this as the answer when the timer allows me.